# $a_k\in(-1,1)$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ & $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{1+a_k}$ is convergent. WTS $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^4$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Question: Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $a_k\in(-1,1)$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is convergent, and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{1+a_k}$ is convergent.  We want to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^4$ is convergent.

Thoughts: My first thought was that we should split the $a_k$ from $(-1,0)$ and from $[0,1)$, if we could even do that...I suppose all my thoughts wouldn't use that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{1+a_k}$ is convergent, and so I feel like I am just not getting off to the right start.  Any help is greatly appreciated!   Maybe it would be best to show things are in $L_1$....?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I believe we can prove the stronger statement that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$ converges.*

Since $\sum_k a_k$ converges, we have $|a_n|\leq 1/2$ for all large enough $n$, say $n\geq N$ for some $N\geq 1$. For any $n\geq N$,
$$
a_n^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{a_n^2}{a_n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(a_n - \frac{a_n}{a_n +1}\right)
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{k=N}^n a_k^2 \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{k=N}^n a_k - \sum_{k=N}^n \frac{a_k}{a_k +1}\right)
$$
for any $n\geq N$. Can you conclude?

Comment: Note that it is *not* true that $\sum_{k}|a_k|$ converges in general. Taking $a_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: why proving $\sum_k a_k^2$ stronger than $\sum_k a_k^4$? coz we can use the comparison test?

Comment: @Rose: yes: one is stronger because it implies the other (and not vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

First, the series :
$$\sum \dfrac{x_n^2}{1 + x_n} = \sum x_n - \sum \dfrac{x_n}{1 + x_n}$$
converges.
The series $\sum x_n$ converges then $x_n \to 0$ therefore :
$$\dfrac{x_n^2}{1 + x_n} \sim x_n^2$$
We can conclude that $\sum x_n^2$ converges.
Finally :
$$\sum x_n^4$$
converges coz :
$$x_n^4 = x_n^2 x_n^2 = o(x_n^2)$$